# Java: Strip everything before third slash

Tags: java

I'm currently in the progress of making a java application, one of the functions is showing related emails and documents.

But the full path to the email (on a sharepoint server) is displayed in the application, for obvious reasons the number of characters depends on the title of the email and the location.

But they all have the same in common, there are ALWAYS 3 slashes in the title.

Like this: `Myserver/client/caseID/Title of Email here`

Is it possible to get Java to "count" the number of slashes and just delete everything before the third slash?

Comment: how about just grabbing the text after the last slash?

Comment: refer to `String#lastIndexOf` and `String#substring` methods... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: refer to regular expressions (caputing groups http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Split function to achieve this.

```
String value="Myserver/client/caseID/Title of Email here";
value=value.split("\\/")[3];
System.out.println("your value is "+value);
```

Comment: If for any reason I get only 2 slashes?

Comment: The questioner said like @ ALWAYS@ , it is in the 3rd position. Gone with the same assumption.

Comment: Yes, probably that's what he knows by now. Besides what somebody else I like to code my apps the most error-free I can. I think it doesn't hurt to evaluate the array's size to be 4 or more...

Comment: In that case , i use indexOf and substring to accomplish that . @GarisMSuero

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
String s = "Myserver/client/caseID/Title of Email here";
int i = s.lastIndexOf('/');
if (i != -1)
    System.out.println(s.substring(i));
else
    System.out.println("no slashes");
```

Comment: You want `substring(i+1)`, no?

Comment: I had that originally, but OP said "delete everything before the third slash".

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`replaceFirst`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) function is one way to go:

```
String yourString = "Myserver/client/caseID/Title of Email here";
System.out.println(yourString.replaceFirst("([^/]+/){3}", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
s = s.replaceFirst(".*?/.*?/.*?(?=/)", "");
```

Comment: if he always wants the last part I would rather recommend `.*/(.*)`. Edited: Well, not with the replaceFirst...